# Trouble with Spring @ConfiurationProperties extending Mao

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, configurationproperties

I am trying to load come properties from config using the Spring @Configuration & @ConfigurationProperties combination. I have a POJO that extends HashMap<Integer, String> and has a single variable inside. (See `MyConfigPojo` below).  From the .yaml file, I have the same shape. However, when booting up the app, I get an error when trying to parse the string for the defaultValue into an Integer.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationPropeties(prefix = "my-config")
public class MyConfigPojo extends HashMap<Integer, String> {

  private String defaultValue;

  private String getValueForIdOrDefault(int id); // this.get(id) OR ELSE defaultValue
}
```

In config I have this:

```
myConfig:
  1: "my first value"
  23: "my 23rd value"
  defaultValue: "cheese"
```

Which results in a

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
Description:
Failed to bind properties under 'myPackage' to MyConfigPojo:
Property: myConfig[1]
Value: cheese
```

I thought that was weird, so I turned on TRACE logs and found this:

```
99 common frames omittedCaused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "defaultValue" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Is there a way to intercept reading this file or to tell Spring how to set the values properly?

Comment: What are trying to do? jus want to read the properties from yaml to map right?

Comment: Basically I will have a list of these Int -> String maps each with its own default value that I'd like to be read from config.
e.g.:`[{1: "firstMapValueForKey1", 4: "fistMapValaueForKey4", defaultValue: "defaultValueForFirstMap"}, {2: "secondMapValueForKey2",  9: "secondMapValueForKey9",  defaultValue: "secondMapDefaultValue"}]`

Comment: Your actual problem is using trying to read a map value a: b(key: value), so you have to keep the key type consistent, initially you are using integer, But defaultValue is string, so you are getting NumberFormatException

Comment: I know that I can just change the type of the Map and would get rid of the problem. I am trying to see if there's a way not to do it that way. e.g. with @ConfigurationPropetiesBinding

Comment: Oh great, you did not mention anything about this annotation @ConfigurationPropetiesBinding in question. Anyway, goodluck

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a Map from .yml file, for that, you need `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation enough, don't need `@Configuration` annotation(if using spring boot). If you are using spring-framework, you need @Configuration also.

Use this example:

```
myConfig:
  map:
    1: "my first value"
    23: "my 23rd value"
    defaultValue: "cheese"
```

MyConfigPojo.java

```
package com.org;


import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.util.HashMap;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-config")
public class MyConfigPojo {

    private HashMap<String, String> map;

    public HashMap<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

Now, you can Autowire this `MyConfigPojo` class anywhere(for instance, in controller class) and read those map keys and values.

```
@Autowired
MyConfigPojo pojo;
```

Now, you have considered keys & Values as `String` datatype for that Map, you will not get `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Good to know about `@Configuration`.  
I know I can switch the Map from `<Integer, String>` to `<String, String>`, but I am trying to find a way around that. e.g. using some form of @ConfigurationPropertiesBinding

Comment: When I removed the `@Configuration` annotation, I started receiving this error
`Field myPojo in mypackage required a bean of type 'myPackage.MyPojo' that could not be found.

Comment: Yeah, if you are using spring boot, you dont need it. In Spring, you need it.